# What's the difference between a generic constraint of <T: Any> and no constraint <T>

Tags: swift, generics

I've seen some code that uses constraints like `<T: Any>` and can't find the difference in the docs between that and not specifying a constraint. Is there any difference at all, like restricting to non optionals?

Comment: I firmly believe there is no difference. I just tried passing optionals, closures, meta types, tuples. They all work with `<T: Any>`. I think all values can be put to `Any`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constraint is indeed redundant, as all types are subtypes of `Any` (including `Optional`).

Internally, the compiler actually models the type `Any` as being a protocol composition type 
(e.g `P1 & P2`) consisting of *zero protocols*. There's no way to spell this in the language, which is why `Any` isn't defined in the standard library anymore<sup>1</sup>, it's just a keyword that's parsed as a type.

So the constraint `T : Any` is literally interpreted as "`T` must conform to all of the protocols in this empty list of protocols", which is quite evidently a redundant constraint. Really the compiler ought to warn on it (I have actually started working on a patch to do so – aiming to open a pull request sometime this week all things going well).

<sub>1. `Any` used to be defined in the standard library as a `typealias` for `protocol<>`, when protocol compositions were spelt `protocol<P1, P2>` rather than `P1 & P2`.</sub>